# Impact on Visual Studio Version changed on the solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I recently pushed changes on our .NET 5 project, and on my pull request I notice the Visual Studio Version of the solution has changed from from 16 to 17 after adding the following nuget packages:

```
Autofac.Extras.Moq Version="6.1.0" 
Microsoft.Extensions.Options Version="5.0.0"
MockQueryable.Moq Version="5.0.2"
```

is this the case?

1. What is the cause of this?
2. Will it have impact on the app?
3. Will other developers on the team going to have a problem?

Comment: version 16 of Visual Studio is Visual Studio 2019, version 17 is Visual Studio 2022. I'm guessing that someone on the project is using VS 2022.

Comment: I think there's a few of us using VS 2022, but this change only suddenly happened on my end.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it. It just means that somebody committed the change. It probably won't affect too much.

Comment: It does not affect compiled applications. Either backtrack the node, or everyone else upgrades to the newer version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Sometimes there are people on the team who will not commit the changes made to the solution file after they upgrade Visual Studio--because others on the team have not yet upgraded. But, apparently, someone on your team did commit those changes after they upgraded.
2. It won't impact the compiled application.
3. Other developers will either have to upgrade Visual Studio--or they will have to not commit the solution file with a degraded version number back into source control